# How to print a String that's stored in an object that's stored in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rubik[][][] pos = new CubePos[3][3][3];
        CubePos getter = new CubePos();

        //RED FACING FRONT, ORANGE ON BACK
        //BLUE ON TOP, GREEN ON BOTTOM
        //YELLOW TO THE RIGHT OF USER, WHITE TO THE LEFT OF USER
        pos[1][1][2] = new CubePos(new CubeOne("R", CubeColor.Color.Red), CubeColor.Color.Red);
        pos[2][1][1] = new CubePos(new CubeOne("Y", CubeColor.Color.Yellow), CubeColor.Color.Yellow);
        pos[1][1][0] = new CubePos(new CubeOne("O", CubeColor.Color.Orange), CubeColor.Color.Orange);
        pos[0][1][1] = new CubePos(new CubeOne("W", CubeColor.Color.White), CubeColor.Color.White);
        pos[1][2][1] = new CubePos(new CubeOne("B", CubeColor.Color.Blue), CubeColor.Color.Blue);
        pos[1][0][1] = new CubePos(new CubeOne("G", CubeColor.Color.Green), CubeColor.Color.Green);
```

How do I print the "R" "Y" "O", etc. if it is stored in an array?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include information about the `CubeOne` and `CubePos` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(pos[1][1][2].getCubeOne().getCubeOneLetter());
```

Replace the method names by yours.